# Updating an existed Symfony project from 2.8.* to 4.26.3

Tags: symfony, composer-php

Im trying to update an existed symfony project in the composer.json I had the following:

```
 "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.9",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.8.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~5.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~2.7"
},
```

Then I changed it to :

```
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.4.13",
    "symfony/symfony": "4.26.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^2.9.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.4.2",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^3.1.0",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0.19",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^5.0.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3",
    "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
    "liuggio/excelbundle": "^2.1"

},
"require-dev": {
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~3.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^4.4.2"
},
```

I already read the old answers of people who were trying to update older versions to newest versions of symfony but nothing works so I think I might be doing something wrong.
I even tried to update it to 5.1 but still not results. This is the ERROR i get whenever I run composer install:

```
Problem 1
  - Root composer.json requires symfony/symfony 4.26.3, found symfony/symfony[2.0.4, ..., 2.8.x-dev, v3.0.0-BETA1, ..., 3.4.x-dev, v4.0.0-BETA1, ..., 4.4.x-dev, v5.0.0-BETA1, ..., 5.4.x-dev, 6.0.x-dev] but it does not match the constraint.
Problem 2
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.20 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.3.4 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.3.7 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.21 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.22 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.23 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.24 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.25 (conflict analysis result)
  - Root composer.json requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ^2.4.2 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.4.2].
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.39 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.25 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.40 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.27 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.41 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.30 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.42 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.2.7 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.43 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.2.9 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.44 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.2.10 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.45 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.2.12 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.46 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.3.0 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.47 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.3.1 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.48 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v5.3.3 (conflict analysis result)
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/http-kernel v3.4.49 (conflict analysis result)
  - Root composer.json requires sensio/distribution-bundle ^5.0.19 -> satisfiable by sensio/distribution-bundle[v5.0.19, ..., v5.0.25].
  - sensio/distribution-bundle v5.0.19 requires symfony/http-kernel ~2.3|~3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/http-kernel[v2.3.0, ..., v2.8.52, v3.0.0, ..., v3.4.49].
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.38.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.37.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.36.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.35.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.34.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.33.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.32.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.31.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.30.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.29.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.28.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.27.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.26.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.25.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.24.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.23.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.22.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.21.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.20.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.19.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.18.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.17.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.16.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.15.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.4.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.18.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.17.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.16.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.15.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.3.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.2.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.1.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v3.0.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.52.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.51.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.50.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.49.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.48.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.47.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.46.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.45.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.44.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.43.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.42.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.41.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.40.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.39.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.38.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.37.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.36.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.35.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.34.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.33.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.32.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.31.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.30.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.29.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.28.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.27.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.26.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.25.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.24.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.23.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.22.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.21.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.20.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.19.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.18.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.17.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.16.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.15.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.8.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.52.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.51.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.50.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.49.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.48.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.47.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.46.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.45.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.44.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.43.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.42.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.41.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.40.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.39.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.38.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.37.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.36.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.35.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.34.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.33.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.32.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.31.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.30.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.29.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.28.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.27.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.26.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.25.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.24.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.23.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.22.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.21.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.20.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.19.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.18.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.17.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.16.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.15.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.7.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.6.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.5.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.4.0.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.42.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.41.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.40.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.39.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.38.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.37.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.36.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.35.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.34.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.33.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.32.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.31.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.30.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.29.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.28.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.27.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.26.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.25.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.24.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.23.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.22.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.21.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.20.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.19.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.18.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.17.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.16.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.15.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.14.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.13.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.12.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.11.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.10.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.9.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.8.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.7.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.6.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.5.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.4.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.3.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.2.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.1.
  - symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.22 conflicts with symfony/http-kernel v2.3.0.
  - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.4.2 requires symfony/doctrine-bridge ^4.4.22|^5.2.7|^6.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/doctrine-bridge[v4.4.22, ..., v4.4.30, 
v5.2.7, ..., v5.3.7].
  - Conclusion: don't install symfony/doctrine-bridge v4.4.24 (conflict analysis result)
```

Please I've been struggling with this for days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Create a fresh 4.4 project, install the three third party bundles that you have used and use the resulting composer.json file as a starting point.  Just be aware that since you got stuck on what is by far the easiest part of the process, you won't get very far.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not check this package by package? For example, `symfony/swiftmailer-bundle` with the given version constraint `~2.3` installs v2.6.7 which is four years old and incompatible with Symfony 4

Comment: "but it does not match the constraint." - start with this. 

There is no such tag as 4.26.x. Try ^4.2, which is the same as 4.2.*

Answer (score 4):

Some  months ago, I did the same upgrade from 2.4 -> 2.8 -> 3.4 ->4.4. So I can tell you how I did it.

Advises:

1. Create a base of smoke test of your principal routes with PHPunit
2. Do the upgrade by major version, each jump on the version contains some deprecations and is assuming you are jumping from the previous version, read the change log.
3. Use the version of PHP5.6 on SF2.8 and SF3.4 (this version is compatible but 3.0 is not, jump directly to 3.4), don't try to upgrade directly to PHP > 7.4
4. After you make the upgrade of 3.4, jump to PHP 7.1, skip the version 7.0
5. After you make the upgrade of PHP 7.1 now you can upgrade the SF4.4

PHP 7.2 and superior, contains some libraries not supported by default, so, that is the reason to use PHP 7.1, those libraries are on the limit, if you are not using, you can do the upgrade more easy.

Remember even if you can have a stable composer.json with SF4.4, some uses of code in SF2.8 are valid, but not anymore on 3.4 or 4.4. In this part I'm referring of you application, not the dependencies.

Read the following courses on this order.

1. [Upgrade from 2.8 to 3.0](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony3-upgrade)
2. [Upgrade from 3 to 4](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony4-upgrade)

Remember, the most easy way to do the upgrade is with automated tests.

Comment: Is there any reason to still use PHP 5.6? I'm currently working on a Symfony 2.8 project, running on PHP 7.1, and there are no incompabilities

Comment: well, based on the composer json, the most common version to use SF2.8 is with PHP5.6, but if you project is already using 7.1 is fine, you can do the upgrade directly to SF4.4 and then work with the PHP version to upload to 7.4
I forget something, change the version of your PHP on the composer.json 
"php": ">=CURRENT_VERSION_USING".

Comment: 2.8 does indeed run fine on 7.1.  Still have a couple of projects there myself.  2.x was never tested on 7.4.  Some of the rather annoying 'fixes' for the count function (introduced in 7.2) will definitely blow up existing code.  BTW, 3.4 has been tested on 7.4 and works fine.